# String Split in JavaScript and get the middle data

Tags: javascript, html

I have a string then i would like to split it into 3

```
   <script>
   function myFunction() {
    var str = "I LOVE YOU";
    var res = str.split(" ");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
   }
   </script>
```

then i would like to display "LOVE" only

```
LOVE
```

I tried this:

```
   <script>
   function myFunction() {
    var str = "I LOVE YOU";
    var res = str.split(" ",2);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
   }
   </script>
```

The result is:

```
I,LOVE
```

And what if i have

```
var str = "Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday";
```

and I would like to display "Thurday Friday Saturday" only

```
Thursday Friday Saturday
```

Is there any way for me to get the middle spliced string?

Comment: yes get the length and find the middle.but what if it's even?

Comment: `var res = str.split(" ")[1];`

Comment: @4castle Out of curiosity, why didn't you post this as the answer, but a comment? I've been seeing so many people keeping shorter answers in the comments and was wondering if it was a faux pas to have short answers as Answers or not (vs Comments)

Comment: @4castle actually he want the middle one in second case `Thursday` not `Tuesday`

Comment: @Tor I usually write answers in the comment section if the question is super simple, is likely a duplicate, or if I don't have time to write a fully fleshed-out answer and so I'll just leave a hint.

Comment: @4castle Ah gotcha, thanks

Comment: Sorry about the question, i make some changes not "Thurdays" how about like this "Thursday Friday Saturday"

Comment: @Zach Your edit makes no sense. Why “Thursday Friday Saturday”? This isn’t the middle, as you specified. Does that follow any logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var words = str.split(" ");
var res = words[Math.floor(words.length / 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let str = "Un jour mon prince";
let arr = str.split(' ');
let mid = Math.floor(arr.length / 2) ;
let res = arr[mid];

alert("The middle word is… " + res);
```

Or more concisely:

```
let str = "Un jour mon prince";
let arr = str.split(' ');
let res = arr[Math.floor(arr.length / 2)];
```

Answer (score 0):

The javascript split method provides you with the array of all the splitted item. Example :

```
var x = "I LOVE YOU";
var y = x.split(" "); // y = [ I, LOVE, YOU]
```

So you have all the required elements in an array. Now you can just bind the element at required index to the html.

To bind "LOVE", you will have to do something like:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var words = str.split(" ");
var res = words[Math.floor(words.length / 2)]
```

Only works with odd number of words obviously.

Comment: Actually, this would only work with even numbers, because if the length was `3` for example, it would try to index into `1.5`, which isn't defined since arrays only have integer indexes.

Comment: @4castle Yea, use to writing in C# recently. In that case `3/2=1`. Corrected